# Why isn't the clickHandler updating state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to set a background that changes with the active button, the clickHandler will show me the correct id of button but then fails to update the state...something i missed?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import river from "../img/river.jpg";
import snow from "../img/snow.jpeg";
import weather from "../img/weather.jpg";

export default class LowerHeader extends Component {
  state = {
    imgUrl: river
  };

  clickHandler = e => {
    if (e.target.id === 1) {
      this.setState({
        imgUrl: weather
      });
    } else if (e.target.id === 2) {
      this.setState({
        imgUrl: snow
      });
    } else if (e.target.id === 3) {
      this.setState({
        imgUrl: river
      });
    }
    console.dir(e.target);
  };

  render() {
    let styles = {
      backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.imgUrl})`,
      backgroundSize: "cover",
      backgroundPosition: "0% 70%",
      overflow: "hidden"
    };
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div
          className="link-bg-img"
          style={styles}
          alt="Background related to tab chosen"
        />
        <header className="lower-header">
          <ul>
            <NavLink
              to="/maincontent/weather"
              id="1"
              onClick={this.clickHandler}
            >
              Local Weather
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/maincontent/snow" id="2" onClick={this.clickHandler}>
              Snow Report
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/maincontent/river" id="3" onClick={this.clickHandler}>
              River Flows
            </NavLink>
          </ul>
        </header>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

I would like the intial state that loads with the page to stay the same...it works. then should change with each button click after that. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a link to the project: [SwCo App](https://fast-spire-39034.herokuapp.com/) can take a few seconds for the initial load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As UjinT34 said you compare string to a number with a === operator.

Also a more elegant solution to the clickhandler would be:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import river from "../img/river.jpg";
import snow from "../img/snow.jpeg";
import weather from "../img/weather.jpg";

export default class LowerHeader extends Component {
  state = {
    imgUrl: river
  };

  clickHandler = url => {
      this.setState({
        imgUrl: url
      });
  };

  render() {
    let styles = {
      backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.imgUrl})`,
      backgroundSize: "cover",
      backgroundPosition: "0% 70%",
      overflow: "hidden"
    };
    return (
      <>
        <div
          className="link-bg-img"
          style={styles}
          alt="Background related to tab chosen"
        />
        <header className="lower-header">
          <ul>
            <NavLink to="/maincontent/weather" id="1" onClick={()=>{this.clickHandler(weather)}}>
              Local Weather
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/maincontent/snow" id="2" onClick={()=>{this.clickHandler(snow)}}>
              Snow Report
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/maincontent/river" id="3" onClick={()=>this.clickHandler(river)}>
              River Flows
            </NavLink>
          </ul>
        </header>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`e.target.id` is a string and you compare it to a number with `===`. It fails because of different types.

Use something like this:

```
clickHandler = e => {
    const id = parseInt(e.target.id, 10);
    if (id === 1) {
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! overlooking the simple things..much appreciated